# CKEditor parsing html to nodes

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm looking for a way to create a new node in CKEDITOR from some html.

to get a new span node I can do

```
var x = new CKEditor.dom.element('span');
```

but I want the span node to initialize with html similar to span below

```
<span class='link' isPop='false'>Single quote's and special character!</span>
```

so question is:

is there anything available in CKEDITOR which creates a new node from existing html
e.g

```
var spanHTML = '<span class='link' isPop='false'>Single quote's and special character!</span>';

var newNode = new CKEditor.dom.element('span', spanHTML);
```

or something like

```
var parser = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser();
parser.node = function( tagName, html )
{
    // do something here
};

var newNode = parse.node('span', spanHTML);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `CKEDITOR.dom.element#createFromHtml` method - you can use it to create one element from given outerHtml. Docs http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-static-method-createFromHtml

```
var el = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<span class="a">x</span>' );
el.hasClass( 'a' ); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `appendHtml` method you can use to do that : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-appendHtml